# What would you call a public transport ticket you can make a transfer with?

Tags: word-request

Is there a term for a public ticket you can make a transfer with?

"Transferable ticket" is wrong, I suppose, because it is a ticket more people can use (it is not bound to a single physical human being).

What is the correct term?

Comment: What do you mean by "you can make a transfer with?" From bus to train?

Comment: @Jan From bus to another bus, for example.

Comment: @Jan Such a ticket is usually valid for N minutes and you can use whatever bus, metro or tram  you want during this time. (it is just the opposite of how public Paris Metro tickets work - if you want to go by second train there, you have to buy a new ticket)

Answer (score 1):

**A transfer ticket**

> Also, if you change from metro to bus or from tram to trolley, you
>   might think that you need two single tickets, but that’s not true.
>   There is a special kind of ticket for these situations – **a transfer
>   ticket** ([welovebudapest.com](https://welovebudapest.com/en/toplists/tips-and-tricks-for-navigating-budapests-public-transport-system/)).
>
> Ticket costs 32 CZK (**transfer ticket** for multiple uses/long ride) and
>   allows you to travel on buses, the metro and trams for up to 90
>   minutes ([prague-guide.co.uk](https://www.prague-guide.co.uk/prague-public-transport/)).

This is different from *transverable ticket,* which can be used by different people. Non-transferable ticket cannot be transferred from one passenger to another ([Businessdictionary](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/non-transferable-ticket.html)).

Comment: I am not sure this is the correct answer, because the Swiss Transfer Ticket is for a transfer from the airport or the border to any town - it is not mentioned whether you could use different more means of transport or more vehicles.

Comment: I found another example, which says exactly that.

Comment: The Swiss Transfer Ticket just sounds like a standard 'transfer to the hotel of staying' option you would add to a holiday

Comment: No problem, removed that.